# cookie не работает, подключил к node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, cookie

Для проекта использую jwt, cookie ошибок в коде не обнаружено, но при попытке авторизоваться выдает в консоли следующее "

```js
Error: "expiresIN" is not allowed in "options"
    at D:\Synergy-project\nodeJS\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:47:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validate (D:\Synergy-project\nodeJS\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:43:6)
    at validateOptions (D:\Synergy-project\nodeJS\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:58:10)
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (D:\Synergy-project\nodeJS\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:141:5)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Synergy-project\nodeJS\controllers\auth.js:31:35)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

".
Я в javascript новичек, пытаюсь работать с ним только месяц, буду рад, если кто-то более опытный подскажет в чем проблема. Вот код

```js
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { login, password} = req.body;

        if( !login || !password ) {
            return res.status(400).render('login', {
                message: ''
            })
        }

        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?', [login], async (error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) ) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Неверный логин или пароль'
                })
            } else {
                const id = results[0].id;

                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIN: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                console.log("The token is: " + token);

                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }
                res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions );
                res.status(200).redirect("/");
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте привести ошибку полностью, а не только номер строки. Мы все равно не знаем какая это строка

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос, это всё, что выдает терминал. Надеюсь это поможет, спасибо, что обратили внимание на недостаток информации.

Comment: `expiresIn`.....

Comment: С этим элементом что-то не так?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

хз как это работает, но оно работает-_-
Я просто закомментировал вот эту строку:
"expiresIN: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN"